# Select2 Plugin not working while appending new select field dynamically via jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-select2

as said in the title without discussing anymore I'm including my code here,

html code

```
<div class="container">
                                                            <div class="row element no-gutters" id="div_1">
                                                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                                                    <label>Enter Skill Name</label>
                                                                    <input type="text" value="<?=$secure_obj->dataDecrypt($employee_dtl['notice_period'])?>" placeholder="7 Days" name="txtSkillName" id="txtSkillName">
                                                                </div>
                                                                <div class="col-sm-5 row no-gutters">
                                                                    <label>Experience for this Skill</label>
                                                                    <div class="col-6 cmbSkillExpYr">
                                                                        <select name="cmbSkillExpYr" id="cmbSkillExpYr">
                                                                            <option value="">Year</option>
                                                                        </select>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                    <div class="col-6 cmbSkillExpMo">
                                                                        <select name="cmbSkillExpMo" id="cmbSkillExpMo">
                                                                            <option value="">Month</option>
                                                                        </select>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </div>
                                                                <div class="col-sm-3 mt-4">
                                                                    <button class="add ti-plus">Add Skill</button>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
```

javascript code

```
    // Add new element
$(".add").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

   // last <div> with element class id
   var lastid = $(".element:last").attr("id");
   var splitId = lastid.split("_");
   var nextindex = Number(splitId[1]) + 1;

   // Adding new div container after last occurance of element class
   $(".element:last").after("<div class='row element no-gutters' id='div_"+ nextindex +"'></div>");

   // Adding element to <div>
   $("#div_" + nextindex).append('<div class="col-sm-4"><label>Enter Skill Name</label><input type="text" placeholder="7 Days" name="txtSkillName" id="txtSkillName"></div><div class="col-sm-5 row no-gutters"><label>Experience for this Skill</label><div class="col-6 cmbSkillExpYr"><select name="cmbSkillExpYr" id="cmbSkillExpYr"><option value="">Year</option></select></div><div class="col-6 cmbSkillExpMo"><select name="cmbSkillExpMo" id="cmbSkillExpMo"><option value="">Month</option></select></div></div><div class="col-sm-3 mt-4"><button id="remove_' + nextindex + '" class="remove ti-close">Remove Skill</button></div>');

    //fill years in experience field
    $(".cmbSkillExpYr #cmbSkillExpYr").select2({
        data: years,
        tags: true,
    });
    //fill months in experience field
    $(".cmbSkillExpMo #cmbSkillExpMo").select2({
        data: months,
        tags: true
    });

});

    // Remove element
    $('.container').on('click','.remove',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var id = this.id;
        var splitId = id.split("_");
        var deleteindex = splitId[1];

        // Remove <div> with id
        $("#div_" + deleteindex).remove();

    });

    //fill years in experience field
    $(".cmbSkillExpYr #cmbSkillExpYr").select2({
        data: years,
        tags: true
    });
    //fill months in experience field
    $(".cmbSkillExpMo #cmbSkillExpMo").select2({
        data: months,
        tags: true
    });
```

bellow one is a reference for the select options. to avoid writing two much HTML code and making the page heavy I'm using dynamic option including of select2 plugin. the bellow reference javascript included in a separate js file.

```
    let years = [
    {
        id: '1 Year',
        text: '1 Year'
    },
    {
        id: '2 Years',
        text: '2 Years'
    },
    {
        id: '3 Years',
        text: '3 Years'
    },
    {
        id: '4 Years',
        text: '4 Years'
    },
    {
        id: '5 Years',
        text: '5 Years'
    },
    {
        id: '6 Years',
        text: '6 Years'
    },
    {
        id: '7 Years',
        text: '7 Years'
    },
    {
        id: '8 Years',
        text: '8 Years'
    },
    {
        id: '9 Years',
        text: '9 Years'
    },
    {
        id: '10 Years',
        text: '10 Years'
    },
    {
        id: '11 Years',
        text: '11 Years'
    },
    {
        id: '12 Years',
        text: '12 Years'
    },
    {
        id: '13 Years',
        text: '13 Years'
    },
    {
        id: '14 Years',
        text: '14 Years'
    },
    {
        id: '15 Years',
        text: '15 Years'
    },
    {
        id: '16 Years',
        text: '16 Years'
    },
    {
        id: '17 Years',
        text: '17 Years'
    },
    {
        id: '18 Years',
        text: '18 Years'
    },
    {
        id: '19 Years',
        text: '19 Years'
    },
    {
        id: '20 Years',
        text: '20 Years'
    },
    {
        id: '21 Years',
        text: '21 Years'
    },
    {
        id: '22 Years',
        text: '22 Years'
    },
    {
        id: '23 Years',
        text: '23 Years'
    },
    {
        id: '24 Years',
        text: '24 Years'
    },
    {
        id: '25 Years',
        text: '25 Years'
    },
    {
        id: '26 Years',
        text: '26 Years'
    },
    {
        id: '27 Years',
        text: '27 Years'
    },
    {
        id: '28 Years',
        text: '28 Years'
    },
    {
        id: '29 Years',
        text: '29 Years'
    },
    {
        id: '30 Years',
        text: '30 Years'
    },
];

let months = [
    {
        id: '1 Month',
        text: '1 Month'
    },
    {
        id: '2 Months',
        text: '2 Months'
    },
    {
        id: '3 Months',
        text: '3 Months'
    },
    {
        id: '4 Months',
        text: '4 Months'
    },
    {
        id: '5 Months',
        text: '5 Months'
    },
    {
        id: '6 Months',
        text: '6 Months'
    },
    {
        id: '7 Months',
        text: '7 Months'
    },
    {
        id: '8 Months',
        text: '8 Months'
    },
    {
        id: '9 Months',
        text: '9 Months'
    },
    {
        id: '10 Months',
        text: '10 Months'
    },
    {
        id: '11 Months',
        text: '11 Months'
    },
    {
        id: '12 Months',
        text: '12 Months'
    },
];
```

above all this javascript i have included jquery and then the select2 plugin

Comment: 'Not working' is a bit vague -  I think we need to know what is happening or not happening

Comment: after i click add skill select2 css not showing on newly generated select box

Comment: I haven't used Select2 but it looks like the 'id' field of your data should be just an integer (https://select2.org/data-sources/formats)